# How do I unlock a field?

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 7 it is possible to use:

```
$field_name = 'field_name';
$field = field_read_field($field_name);
$field['locked'] = 0; // 0: unlock; 1: lock.
field_update_field($field);
```

How to do this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the related field storage config entity and change the locked status:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('field_storage_config')
  ->load('node.field_foo')
  ->setLocked(FALSE)
  ->save();
```

This is just an example - you should inject the entity type manager instead of calling the global version if contexts allows.